# MacOS: Problem with run aiosqlite for any DB

Tags: python-3.x, database, macos, sqlite, fastapi

I have some ERROR:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiosqlite'**

**Python 3.9 ===== FastAPI ===== SQLite ===== Databases ===== aiosqlite**

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5x5z.png)

[Dependencies screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeBD9.jpg)

[Pip List screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbFRB.jpg)

Test project on FastAPI (including from the example: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-sql-databases/)

The server won't start On Mac OS (any editor: vim, VS Code, "Pycharm", etc.)

on Linux, everything works OK

but on a MacOS I can not run any of the databases (example SQLITE)

The error is as follows: does not see "aiosqlite"! All of the requirements have been seated correct (Python 3.9.5, venv, pip, aiosqlite, sqlalchemy, databases etc. - all of this have been updated)

```
    from typing import List
    
    import databases
    import sqlalchemy
    from fastapi import FastAPI
    from pydantic import BaseModel
    
    
    DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./test.db"
    
    database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)
    metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
    
    
    notes = sqlalchemy.Table(
        "notes",
        metadata,
        sqlalchemy.Column("id", sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True),
        sqlalchemy.Column("text", sqlalchemy.String),
        sqlalchemy.Column("completed", sqlalchemy.Boolean),
    )
    
    
    app = FastAPI()
    
    
    @app.post('/')
    async def root():
        
        return {"message": "Good"}
```

P.S.

```
$ . ./env/bin/activate

$ (env) ➜  testDB2 pip list

Package           Version
----------------- --------
aiosqlite         0.17.0
databases         0.4.3
fastapi           0.63.0
pip               21.1.1
pydantic          1.8.1
setuptools        56.0.0
SQLAlchemy        1.3.24
starlette         0.13.6
typing-extensions 3.10.0.0
```

I've had used a virtual environment venv and run my server with uvicorn by some  in a couple of ways:

1. uvicorn main:app --reload
2. inside the file:

```
    app = FastAPI()
    
    
    @app.get("/")
    async def root():
        return {"message": "Hello World"}
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: How are you running your application? What does `pip freeze` show in the list of installed dependencies? What if you just run the python interpreter and try to import `aiosqlite`?

Comment: I've created an answer in the new edition of my post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Running this command solved the issue for me:

```
pip install databases[sqlite]
```

Refer to this discussion https://github.com/encode/orm/issues/33.